# Java swap and comparisons in Bubble sort

Tags: java

```
public class SortingArray
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      bubbleSort(array1);
   }

   public static void bubbleSort(int[] array2)
   {      
      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("Original order: ");
      for (int element : array2)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      int lastPos;     // Position of last element to compare
      int index;       // Index of an element to compare
      int temp;        // Used to swap to elements
        int count = 0;
      int count2 = 1;

      // The outer loop positions lastPos at the last element
      // to compare during each pass through the array. Initially
      // lastPos is the index of the last element in the array.
      // During each iteration, it is decreased by one.
      for (lastPos = array2.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--)
      {
         // The inner loop steps through the array, comparing
         // each element with its neighbor. All of the elements
         // from index 0 thrugh lastPos are involved in the
         // comparison. If two elements are out of order, they
         // are swapped.
         for (index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++)
         {
            count2++;
            // Compare an element with its neighbor.
            if (array2[index] > array2[index + 1])
            {
                    count++;
               // Swap the two elements.
               temp = array2[index];
               array2[index] = array2[index + 1];
               array2[index + 1] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
      count2++;

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
      for (int element : array2)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      System.out.print("\n Swaps:" + count);
      System.out.print("\n Comparisons:" + count2);


   }

}
```

I am trying to count the comparisons and swaps in a simple bubble sort program, and I know I have the right number of swaps counted (0 in this case), but I cannot figure out how to to keep track of the comparisons. I have to use this specific code with only slight modifications. Could someone help me with understand how many comparisons will be made with this hard coded int array. Right now when I run the program I get 12 and I think that is right but I am not 100 percent positive.

Comment: Why is `count2` being incremented at the end, after all the loops? It should only be incremented after (or before an imminent) compare (of values), of which there is only one such expression. Identify it, and then make sure the previous rule holds.

Comment: And why does `count2` start with 1?

Comment: When I try it inside the look I get 16 comparisons and that seems too high for that amount of numbers in this array.

Comment: @fabian That was a mistake on my part sorry about that I have just been going crazy trying to figure this out and have tried just about everything.

Comment: Now that I have changed the count2 = 0 and place the count2 in the outer for loop I am getting 15 comparisons

Comment: The correct number would be `n * (n-1) / 2` where `n = array2.length`, so 10 in this case. `(x + (x-1) + ... + 1 = (x + 1) * x / 2)`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  The original code does correctly implement bubble sort.

So, keep your original code, just use the below code as a reference to get the comparison count correct.

Anyway, just for reference, here is another common implementation, with correct swap and comparison counts:

```
public class SortingArray
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] array1 = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
      bubbleSort(array1);
   }

   public static void bubbleSort(int[] array2)
   {      
      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("Original order: ");
      for (int element : array2)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      //int lastPos;     // Position of last element to compare
      int index;       // Index of an element to compare
      int temp;        // Used to swap to elements
      int count = 0;
      int count2 = 0;
      boolean swapped = true;


      while (swapped == true)
      {
         swapped = false;
         // The inner loop steps through the array, comparing
         // each element with its neighbor. All of the elements
         // from index 0 thrugh lastPos are involved in the
         // comparison. If two elements are out of order, they
         // are swapped.
         for (index = 0; index < array2.length - 1; index++)
         {
            count2++;
            // Compare an element with its neighbor.
            if (array2[index] > array2[index + 1])
            {
               count++;
               // Swap the two elements.
               temp = array2[index];
               array2[index] = array2[index + 1];
               array2[index + 1] = temp;
               swapped = true;
            }

         }
      }
      //count2++;

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
      for (int element : array2)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      System.out.print("\n Swaps:" + count);
      System.out.print("\n Comparisons:" + count2);


   }

}
```

output:

```
Original order: 
5 4 3 2 1 
Sorted order: 
1 2 3 4 5 
 Swaps:10
 Comparisons:20
```

For your sorted example:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

output:

```
Original order: 
1 2 3 4 5 
Sorted order: 
1 2 3 4 5 
 Swaps:0
 Comparisons:4
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume this is a change I can make even though it is not the specific code I was given, this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Justin: Your Bubble sort uses less Comparisons in the worst case, though. And I'm almost certain it's correct.

Comment: Justin's code does implement bubble sort correctly. It only takes into accout that after the `n`-th iteration the last `n` elements of the array contain the `n` largest values. The other difference to your algorithm is that you stop if no elements were switched, which would be easy to add in Justin's code.

Comment: @fabian, you are correct.  The original algorithm is actually a correct implementation of bubble sort.  I just checked my CLRS Algorithm book.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent and Fabian Thanks for all the help I just started learning about Java sorting algorithms, and it is a little hard to wrap my head around all the different methods, I am still going to have to add selection, insertion, and quick sort to this program. Though I am pretty sure once I get this one correct I will have a much easier time. Thank you, again!